# How to get the following string using escapes?

Tags: java, string, quotes

I have the following String in Java:

```
'People's Republic'
```

And I am trying to get the following literal output:

```
'Peoples\\'s Republic'
```

So far I have tried escaping like this:

```
"\\\\\'"
```

but this only gives me:

```
'People\'s Republic'
```

as a literal out.

Do you know how I could achieve this using escapes?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: `'` in String is not special character so it doesn't require escaping. If you want to create string literal which will represent text `'Peoples\\'s Republic'` then it could look like `"'Peoples\\\\'s Republic'"` (since ``\`` is special in string literal so it requires escaping with another ``\``). If that is not what you want then you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to escape special characters. `'` is not a special character in java. Look at the following example:

```
String string = "People\\\\'s Republic";
System.out.println(string);
```

Output:

```
People\\'s Republic
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use it like this?

```
String str = "People's Republic";
System.out.println(str);
```

**Output**:

```
People's Republic
```